# XSLT: using template match and apply-templates to show only unique values

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <result id="344" part="454" ident="345">    
        <set1>
          <name>John</name>
        </set1>     
        <set2>
          <year>1972</year>
        </set2> 
        <set3>
         <surname>Nash</surname>
        </set3>  
    </result>  
    <result id="344" part="451" ident="341">
        <set1>
          <name>Mickey</name>
        </set1> 
        <set2>
          <year>1966</year>
        </set2>
        <set3>
         <surname>Donay</surname>
        </set3> 
    </result>  
    <result id="344" part="454" ident="342">    
        <set1>
          <name>Peter</name>
        </set1>     
        <set2>
          <year>1979</year>
        </set2>
        <set3>
         <surname>Riley</surname>
        </set3>  
    </result>  
</data>
```

I'm trying to get values of ***set1/name*** and ***set3/surname*** for each unique ***result*** parameters, using `<xsl:template match="">` and `<xsl:apply-templates />`. Also, I tried using `xsl:for-each-group` but all values get displayed.

I used:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="result" group-by="concat(@id, '+', @part, '+', @ident)">
<xsl:apply-templates /> 
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Prior to this I've created template

```
<xsl:template match="//set1|//set3">
```

Desired output, after applying template:

```
John Nash
Mickey Donay
Peter Riley
```

Comment: what you have tried so far. what is expected output

Comment: I've changed question. You can see what I tried and what is desired output.

Comment: In the posted input XML, there seem only to be unique `result` element based on the three attributes `id`, `part` and `ident` you use as the grouping key so it is not clear why/what you want to group and which result you want to output if there a several `result` elements with the same grouping key. Please clarify.

Comment: There are no same result elements. Attribute id is always the same, but other attributes are not. There is always one different. That is why I wanted to use concat to distinct them.

Comment: If there are solely unique elements then you don't need any grouping at all and can just output `//result/concat(set1/name, ' ', set3/surname)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each-group select="//result" group-by="concat(@id, '+', @part, '+', @ident)">
    <xsl:value-of select="set1/name"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="set3/surname"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each-group>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Returns

```
John Nash
Mickey Donay
Peter Riley
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is output the two elements concatenated for each `result` then doing

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="//result/concat(set1/name, ' ', set3/surname)" separator="&#10;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/eiQZDbd/1